# Pandas: Store "row count"

Tags: python, pandas

Using `df.iloc[i]` I can access the `ith` row. I would like to create a column that contains this information.

(For example, after sorting after a relevant criterion), how can I store this information?

Input:

```
           col1
   myIndex 
     12123    a
     11123    b
     10231    a
```

Expected output

```
           col1  iloc
   myIndex 
     12123    a     0
     11123    b     1
     10231    a     2
```

**Optimally, the solution also is implementable for different groups, as per `df.groupby`.**

Comment: Can't you just add the index as an index? won't `df['iloc'] = np.arange(len(df))` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `range`:

```
df['iloc'] = range(len(df))
print df
        col1  iloc
myIndex           
12123      a     0
11123      b     1
10231      a     2
```

Or `np.arange` as mentioned [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627339/pandas-store-row-count/36627417#comment60850638_36627339):

```
df['iloc'] = np.arange(len(df))
print df
        col1  iloc
myIndex           
12123      a     0
11123      b     1
10231      a     2
```

If you need store it by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
print df

        col1  col2
myIndex           
12123      a     1
11123      b     2
10231      a     3
10233      b     3

df['iloc'] = range(len(df))

df['iloc_groups'] = df.groupby('col1', sort=False)['col1'].cumcount()
print df
        col1  col2  iloc  iloc_groups
myIndex                              
12123      a     1     0            0
11123      b     2     1            0
10231      a     3     2            1
10233      b     3     3            1
```